# How to replace all instances of a certain character in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a huge data that TextEditors have difficulty to work. For illustration, I am just sharing a simple example given below:

```
  W1       W2      W3
71,65   833,06   54,955
21,63   131,21   32,90
11,56   23,60    87,55
13,21   93,06    14,05
```

I am trying to replace "," with "." to get output given below:

```
  W1       W2      W3
71.65   833.06   54.955
21.63   131.21   32.90
11.56   23.60    87.55
13.21   93.06    14.05
```

How can I get this output with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `replace` on the entire data frame:

```py
df = df.replace(',', '.', regex=True)
```